# Is there an event when application Window is fully draw?

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the result from `getLocationOnScreen()` as early as possible.

However, putting it in the `onCreate()` event I'll get 0 as my results (which I suspect is because the Window has not been fully created). `onResume()` also does not work unless the application has been brought to background and then front again (i.e. it works on the second call of `onResume()`).

Where should I put `getLocationOnScreen()` so I can get the results early; or maybe is there a way to force `getLocationOnScreen()` to work even before the Window is fully created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The activity lifecycle is

onCreate
onStart
onResume

//app is running

onPause
onStop
onDestroy

All of which you can override

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks